# PHP remove whitespaces - "ghost" lines appear

Tags: php, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I have an HTML Form that queries entries from a MySQL Database and inputs these values into several text areas where they may be edited and these changes subsequently saved.

The SQL/PHP interaction seems to work find, I get the queried information and am able to update the database accordingly. However, whenever I access the (string) information and `echo` this into the text area, there are suddenly four blank lines inserted from nowhere in front of the actual string content.

I do not understand where these blank lines are coming from and moreover how to get rid of them.

Here's the code from the form text area:

```
<textarea 
    name="MicroLoc_Entry" 
    id="MicroLoc_Entry" 
    style="position:absolute;left:581px;top:45px;width:73px;height:18px;z-index:14;" 
    rows="1" 
    cols="1" 
    spellcheck="false"
>
    <?php 
        include ('db_connect.php'); 
        $ID = $_POST['ItemID']; 
        $sql = "SELECT MicroLoc from Main WHERE ItemID = ".$ID ; 
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql); 
        $res = mysqli_fetch_array($result);  
        $msg = $res['MicroLoc'];
        echo preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', $msg); 
    ?>
</textarea>
```

Using either `ltrim($string)` or `preg_replace('/\s+/g', '', $string)` or `preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', $string)` does only reduce the whitespace to two additional blank lines but does not remove them all.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Try to fit the opening php tag to the preceding closing HTML tag. similar for ending PHP tag... Those are white spaces that get rendered.

Comment: Unrelated, but learn about https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1839439) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: @Dharman this was already said by Olaf. There's enough to cast `$ID` to integer. And this is not solves the problem.

Comment: @trincot Thanks a lot, executing the php tag in front of the whole html parts actually did solve my blank lines problem :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Run your code before the `<textarea>` and then echo the result inside `<textarea>`.
So, if your code generate any newlines - it will be outside `<textarea>`.

```php
<?php 
        include ('db_connect.php'); 
        $ID = $_POST['ItemID']; 
        $sql = "SELECT MicroLoc from Main WHERE ItemID = ".intval($ID) ; 
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql); 
        $res = mysqli_fetch_array($result);  
        $msg = $res['MicroLoc'];
        $echomsg = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', $msg); 
?>
<textarea 
    name="MicroLoc_Entry" 
    id="MicroLoc_Entry" 
    style="position:absolute;left:581px;top:45px;width:73px;height:18px;z-index:14;" 
    rows="1" 
    cols="1" 
    spellcheck="false"
><?php echo $echomsg; ?></textarea>
```

Also please be sure, that there is no any other spaces or newlines between the `<textarea>` and `</textarea>` tags. Because these also can be the source of unwanted symbols.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1839439) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: Won’t use of intval remove the injection problem?

Comment: @krylov123 Thank you, removing the php tag did help the immediate problem :-)